# Not all paths return a value. - Optional return?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting the error "Not all paths return a value", and I totally understand why.

As you can see I want to redirect the person isn't logged in, and obviously there is no return view.

I'm sure I'm going about this incorrectly. How should I be trying to do this?

```
    public ActionResult Confirmation (Order Order) {
        if (Session["CompanyID"] == null)
        {
            string url = Request.Url.Host;
            if (Request.Url.Port != null)
            {
                url = url + Request.Url.Port;
            }
            url = url + "/signin.asp";
            Response.Redirect(url);


        }
        else
        {

            int userID = (int)Session["CompanyID"];
            Corp_User User = Repository.CorpUserDetails(userID);

            return View(new OrderLocation { Order = Order, Location = WhygoRepository.RoomDetails(Order.roomId).First(), Corp_User = User });
        }


    }
```

Please note that I need to redirect to a classic ASP page, not an MVC action..

Comment: +1 for "I'm sure I'm going about this incorrectly."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return a RedirectResult - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult.aspx

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Anyone have any problems with this approach?

Comment: It's almost perfect, but the RedirectResult action returns an HTTP status code of 302 (temporarily moved), where you probably want HTTP 303 (see other) or 307 (temporary redirect). Maybe not a big deal, most browsers interpret 302 as 303 anyway :)

Comment: You could write a custom RedirectResult that sets the status code, as described here - http://thethoughtfulcoder.com/blog/62/A-way-to-return-a-permanent-301-redirect-result-in-ASPNET-MVC-RedirectResult-returns-a-temporary-302-redirect

Comment: @MattDavey: In MVC 3 RedirectResult has an optional parameter to make the redirect temporary (302) or permanent (301).

Answer (score 4):

You must return a ActionResult. Use "RedirectToAction".

```
    public ActionResult Confirmation(Order Order)
    {
        if (Session["CompanyID"] == null)
        {
            string url = Request.Url.Host;
            if (Request.Url.Port != null)
            {
                url = url + Request.Url.Port;
            }
            url = url + "/signin.asp";
            return RedirectToAction(<YOUR ACTION>);


        }
        else
        {

            int userID = (int)Session["CompanyID"];
            Corp_User User = Repository.CorpUserDetails(userID);

            return View(new OrderLocation { Order = Order, Location = WhygoRepository.RoomDetails(Order.roomId).First(), Corp_User = User });
        }


    }
```

Comment: @dknaack - Thanks for the answer. I can't do a RedirectToAction in this case because I have go redirect to a classic asp login page....

Comment: @iKode, that complicates things a little. In that case you'll need to map a route to your classic asp login page so that the MVC engine skips it..

Comment: @iKode: Ok thats complicate. I would do a redirect as you done before and return null in this case. Thats not real mvc but it works. You can map a route too. So map a route if you like to do it right, return null if you need a quick n dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a good question actually. See dknaack's answer for a solution in your particular case however in other circumstances we might not be so lucky.

Technically this situation is very logical. Redirect just opens up a new request and either lets the current request handle itself nicely or forcefully close itself. In all cases the current method needs a return value. If Redirect lets the current process handle itself nicely meaning you should have a return value that makes sense.

I think one solution would be to throw a specific exception after the redirect. Something like:

```
public string GetCurrentUserName()
{
    if (!authenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect(LoginScreen);

        throw new UnresolvedMethodException();
    }
    else
    {
        return UserName;
    }
}
```

Returning NULL is an option i wouldnt put my money on since NULL might also mean that there is no UserName Set (in the above case, a user might login using his email making the username optional).

Comment: Yeh just something i came up with

Answer (score -2):

Just put `return null;` under `Response.Redirect(url);` It will never actually reach that position, but it will get rid of the compiler error.

Comment: See other answers, returning null isn't pretty

Comment: That's just not true. Null is the default value of objects that aren't initialized. What's dangerous is using initialized objects without real values in them.

Comment: @hcb so thinking in semantics, *what does it mean* when an MVC controller action returns null??

Comment: Why should it be better to call Response.Redirect() and return null when you could return a RedirectTo-action result?

Comment: @Onkelborg +1, I think a lot of these Response.Redirect recommendations are coming from WebForms guys who don't have much experience with MVC...

Answer (score -3):

You could return null and check for that.

edit: I was way to quick, ignore me :P